# Connecting MySQL to JasperReports Server

Tags: java, mysql, database, jasperserver

I'm trying to connect my *JasperReports Server* to a remote *MySQL* server. I'm pretty sure I have the driver in the right place (as it shows up as an option in the *JR Server*  dashboard). Here's the dashboard:

[image]

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to 54.213.92.113:3306 : 
Connection refused at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.get(SQLExceptionMapper.java:136) 
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.throwException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:106) 
at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:114) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571) 
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215) 
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.DataSourceAction.testJdbcDataSource(DataSourceAction.java:482)
```

Does anyone have any idea as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: haha...ok, would you mind cluing me in as to why please?

Comment: @pj409 Did you try to make connection with simple *Java* code (from server side)?

Comment: It looks like you have the wrong IP address or port number (3306 is standard but not mandatory) or the MySQL server isn't running.  That's what "connection refused" generally means -- it's not an authentication issue, it's a basic IP connectivity problem.  Test the connection with `telnet 54.213.92.113 3306` --this will give you a message with the server version like `N
5.6.10-log��LTB-YZ:�\db?PXH?EzW%mysql_native_password` if the server is accessible (this example, the server is MySQL 5.6.10) and an error like "connection timed out" or "connection refused" if there is no IP connectivity.

Comment: yep, I got 'Connection Refused'. Is this because the MySQL server isn't allowing access from remote machines? Should I change the root privileges?

Comment: hmm...the firewall seems to be allowing port 3306 just fine too.

Comment: Can you do a telnet to the IP and address and connect?

Comment: No, I already tried that. I think it's because my MySQL server isn't allowing connections from remote machines for some reason. trying to figure that out now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give privileges to the user that you want to connect:

check with show privileges

```
+-----------------+------------+
| Host            | User       |
+-----------------+------------+
| %               | username   |
| localhost       | username   |
+-----------------+------------+
```